Using Powershell to replace the last character in a file
I have created a Powershell script that lists files in a folder to a file.
The script then manipulates the file to create a SQL script.  The file then looks something like this:
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM Invoices WHERE DocNum IN (
123456,
123457,
123458,
123459,

I would like to change the last comma to a closing bracket.  What is the best approach?
Thanks
Carrot
I have tried variations on the scripts in How to replace a character at the end of a string/file? and others
But the last record is not being updated

[Edit] the question and show the script that generates the select statement. It needs a piece of logic that cheks if you got more data and comma or no more and a closing parenhesis.

you should be using sqlparameter to inject those values instead of this. example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78330104/15339544

How did you get the comma at the end?  It is probably easier to not put the comma at the end in the first place.

(Get-Content $FilePath -Raw).TrimEnd() -replace ',$', ')' |
Set-Content $FilePath


I think I have it...
# Read the file as a single string
$content = Get-Content $FilePath -Raw

# Trim the end of the big string
$content = $content.TrimEnd()

# Find length of $content
$contentlen = $content.Length-1

# Set content to one less char
$content = $content.Substring(0,$contentlen)

# Add ) to content
$content = $content + ')'

# Write the content back out
$content | Set-Content $FilePath -NoNewLine

